Recycler item not filling width without inflating from parent
I know similar questions have been asked multiple times, but the usual answer is simply use .inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false). In my case, where the RecyclerView is nested within a ViewPager2 in combination with a TabLayout, the suggested solution does fill the width but then seems to lead to a fixed height for the recycler, which is not what i want.
Here is the current result, followed by the target:


Is there a solution that will not lead to me having to compromise on either filling the width XOR the height?
Here is the main layout which includes the viewpager and tabLayout, whose child is the recyclerview in question:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vBgMask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/core_sheet_mask" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/core_sheet_default_margin_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/core_sheet_default_margin_top">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/layoutContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/core_bg_bottom_sheet"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                style="@style/BtnClose"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/core_btnClose_marginTop"
                android:contentDescription="@null" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/core_margin_screenHorizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvIncidentTitle"
                        style="@style/Text.H4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                        tools:text="Title of Incident" />

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tlIncidentInfo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:background="@color/quantum_white_100"
                        app:tabGravity="start"
                        app:tabMinWidth="60dp"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabPaddingBottom="16dp"
                        app:tabPaddingEnd="16dp"
                        app:tabPaddingStart="16dp"
                        app:tabPaddingTop="16dp"
                        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Text.Tab" />

                    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                        android:id="@+id/vpIncidentDetails"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingTop="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Text.Sub1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/core_description"
                            android:textColor="@color/core_dark60" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvIncidentDesc"
                            style="@style/Text.Body"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/core_textOverline"
                            tools:text="Description of Incident" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvMeasuresHeader"
                            style="@style/Text.Sub1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                            android:text="@string/flightplan_incident_view_measures"
                            android:textColor="@color/core_dark60"
                            android:visibility="visible" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvMeasures"
                            style="@style/Text.Body"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/core_textOverline"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            tools:text="Measures for incident hazard" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvConsequencesHeader"
                            style="@style/Text.Sub1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                            android:text="@string/flightplan_incident_view_consequences"
                            android:textColor="@color/core_dark60"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvConsequences"
                            style="@style/Text.Body"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/core_textOverline"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            tools:text="Consequences of incident hazard" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            </ScrollView>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>

Here is the "Activity" tab's layout which is basically the recyclerview in question:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/core_margin_s"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

and here is the layout of one of the items (the one containing a cardview in the images):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/lTimeline"
        layout="@layout/timeline_node_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvActivityFollowUpStatusTitle"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            tools:text="dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm follow up added by Username" />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:background="@color/quantum_white_100"
            android:padding="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/core_dark10"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFollowUp"
                    style="@style/Text.Body2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:text="I'm baby hexagon +1 lumbersexual ascot hammock distillery. Hammock umami taxidermy, ethical affogato disrupt dreamcatcher salvia hella jean shorts bicycle rights bruh banh mi. " />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvDocuments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

